# Azure Load Testing External Request (API call) Performance / load testing with Individual Call performance details

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, azure-load-testing

I want to perform load testing of Single Page Application. So i have created JMeter script for that and it is working fine from my single machine for concurrent users. But i want to create actual concurrent users scenario from different machine or location. For that reason i am trying to use Azure Load Testing service and there want to use JMeter script which i have created on my local machine.

Please let me know if Azure Load testing service support below points : -

1. Is it possible to test performance of API call which are going to other servers (non Azure).
2. Is it possible to track performance report like JMeter for each API call individually.

Please let me know if any clue on above problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/load-testing/#overview)

> Enable developers and testers to generate high-scale load and run simulations that reveal actionable insights into app performance, scalability, and capacity with a fully managed load-testing service. Create tests quickly without prior knowledge of load testing tools, or **upload your existing Apache JMeter scripts**. Gain specialized recommendations backed by comprehensive metrics and analytics, and support continuous improvement through automated continuous integration and continuous delivery (CI/CD) workflows—all with a testing service built for Azure.

So it should be possible to run your JMeter scripts from Azure. If your system under test is reachable from the Internet you it doesn't matter where it's deployed.

If not and your application is only accessible from your local [Intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) - you will have to go for [JMeter Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)